# Why the error message returned from http interceptor is ignored?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an angular project that calls api with `HttpInterceptor` like below.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => this.errorHandler(error)));
}

private errorHandler(response: HttpEvent<any>): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  console.log(response)
throw response;
}
```

And the api is set up in service file like below

```
  getData(data1: string): Observable<data2: number> {   
    return this.http.post<{data2: number;>('search/', {data1} );
  }
```

The api is called in componenet like below.

```
this.someService.getData('hi').subscribe( res => {    
    console.log('res wont response because error its find and expected');
}),(err=>{console.log('hello?');console.log(err);} );
```

I expect `"hellow?" console log` yet it only return the `"response"` `console log`. Why is it skipping the `err` subscription and how can I make the `err` subscription works? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `throw` can be the problem. You can try `return throw`. But the correctly way is to use `throwError`. My Interceptor (updated to newest RxJS syntax) looks so:

```
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  ...
   if (authToken == null) { // Do HERE what you want
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    return next.handle(authRequest as any).pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => {
        if (error['status'] !== 401 && error['status'] !== 403) {
          return throwError(() => error);
        }
  ...
}
```

So the **return `throwError(() => error);` does the trick I think.

## Update

A wrong syntax in the httpClient is the problem. The correctly is:

```
this.someService.getData('hi').subscribe( res => {    
    console.log('res wont response because error its find and expected');
  },
  err => {console.log('hello?');console.log(err);
  }
);
```

But this is deprecated. So the new way is this:

```
this.someService.getData('hi').subscribe(
  {
    next: (res) => {    
      console.log('res wont response because error its find and expected');
    },
    error: (err) => { console.log('hello?');console.log(err);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I have try to change the `throw response` to `return throwError(() => response);`, unfortunately, it still skip the `err` execution.

Comment: Im suspecting if catchError just absorb all error thrown.

Comment: omg its syntax error, I followed their official syntax and it some how works. Thanks for the effort non the less up voted.

Comment: Yes I see. Add update my answer for guys they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In component, you have to use their format instead like this.

```
this.someService.getData('hi').subscribe( {
  next:(res)=>console.log('res wont response because error its finde and expected'),
  error:(err)=>console.log('hello?') 
});
```